# For loop not stopping after finish bool set to true

Tags: c++

sorry this might be a stupid question but i watched a basics on threads video and tried to make a very basic timer. The timer works but it doesn't stop even when the isFinished bool is true? Anyone know the fix, sorry if this is a stupid question and an easy fix.

```
static bool isFinished = false;

void DoWork()
{
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
while (!isFinished)
{
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << "s" <<  "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.90s);
    }
}

}

int main()
{
std::thread worker(DoWork);
std::cin.get();

isFinished = true;
worker.join();
std::cout << "Timer finished";

std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: why would this for loop stop? It has not stop condition

Comment: Most likely not the issue but you do need `std::atomic<bool> isFinished` as the type.

Comment: You have 2 loops, one stops when `isFinished` is true, the other one never stops.

Comment: @Bathsheba it didnt fix the issue as stated, but why does it have to be this type and not a normal bool

Comment: @Mateusz: Because you could end up with a read-write race on the bool.

Answer (score 1):

The inner for loop has no stopping condition and no other mechanism to break/leave it. You may add something like "if(isFinished) break;" inside the for loops body or include the condition in the for(...) itself.

Comment: thanks this fixed the issue! i feel stupid, i thought if the while loop is false then that cant run as the while loop shouldnt. but thanks.

Comment: "*i thought if the while loop is false then that cant run as the while loop shouldnt*" - you are correct, when execution is at the top level of `DoWork()` before the body of the `while` is entered. But once the body of the `while` is entered, the `for` loop takes over, and your statement is no longer true.